# python re split at all space and punctuation except for the apostrophe

Tags: python, string, split, python-re, apostrophe

i want to split a string by all spaces and punctuation except for the apostrophe sign. Preferably a single quote should still be used as a delimiter except for when it is an apostrophe. I also want to keep the delimeters.
example string
`words = """hello my name is 'joe.' what's your's"""`

Here is my re pattern thus far `splitted = re.split(r"[^'-\w]",words.lower())`
I tried throwing the single quote after the ^ character but it is not working.

My desired output is this. `splitted = [hello,my,name,is,joe,.,what's,your's]`

Comment: The hyphen represents ranges in a character class (e.g. `a-z`) so you need to either escape it `[^'\-\w]` or put it at the end `[^'\w-]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make use of lookarounds to split at the desired positions, and use a capture group what you want to keep in the split.

After the split, you can remove the empty entries from the resulting list.

```
\s+|(?<=\s)'|'(?=\s)|(?<=\w)([,.!?])
```

The pattern matches

- `\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\s)'` Match `'` preceded by a whitespace char
- `|` Or
- `'(?=\s)` Match `'` when followed by a whitespace char
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\w)([,.!?])` Capture one of `,` `.` `!` `?` in group 1, when preceded by a word character

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL4zyJ/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Nqwb5T).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\s+|(?<=\s)'|'(?=\s)|(?<=\w)([,.!?])"
words = """hello my name is 'joe.' what's your's"""
result = [s for s in re.split(pattern, words) if s]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'joe', '.', "what's", "your's"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to simply process your list after splitting without accounting for them at first:

```py
>>> words = """hello my name is 'joe.' what's your's"""
>>> split_words = re.split(r"[ ,.!?]", words.lower())  # add punctuation you want to split on
>>> split_words
['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', "'joe.'", "what's", "your's"]
>>> [word.strip("'") for word in split_words]
['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'joe.', "what's", "your's"]
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to add in the question that I also want to keep the delimeters. Is there a way that I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I love regex golf!

```py
words = """hello my name is 'joe.' what's your's"""
splitted = re.findall(r"\b(?:\w'\w|\w)+\b", words)
```

The part in the parenthesis is a group that matches either an apostrophe surrounded by letters or a single letter.

EDIT:

This is more flexible:

```py
re.findall(r"\b(?:(?<=\w)'(?=\w)|\w)+\b", words)
```

It's getting a bit unreadable at this point though, in practice you should probably use Woodford's answer.

Comment: Doesn't quite handle the case of double contractions :): `words = "this couldn't've ever worked"`

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to add in the question that I also want to keep the delimeters. Is there a way that I can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep the delimeters"

Comment: By keep the delimeters I mean that I want to keep the parts of the string that are used to split it. So """hi, my name is joe!""" Would equal ["hi",",","my","name","is","joe","!"

Comment: So you want to keep everything except for spaces. Don't think you can do it with one regex. You'll have to just split on whitespace (`re.split(r"\s+", words)`) then process the result